# Looping through on NSArray objects with button taps

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an array of `NSStrings`, what I'd like to use as a source for a `UIImageView`'s image names.

When the user taps a button I load a new image - next object from the array - into the same image view, that would be the final goal. Actually I have a working, but silly solution, and that's not what I want. I would like to load the string names from an array to the `UIImage`, because this if statement can grow really big with 30-40 object and that's not so reliable. I'm not so fine with for loops so I would really appreciate if somebody could show me how can I get the same result with a `loop` or any other way.

```
- (IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender {

    if (!self.userImageView.image) {


        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"];
        self.userImageView.image = image;
        self.currentDisplayedImageString = @"img1.png";
     // self.currentDisplayedImageString is an ivar, type of NSString
    }
    else {

        if ([self.currentDisplayedImageString isEqualToString:@"img1.png"]) {

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"];
            self.userImageView.image = image;
            self.currentDisplayedImageString = @"img2.png";

        }
        if ([self.currentDisplayedImageString isEqualToString:@"img2.png"]) {

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"];
            self.userImageView.image = image;
            self.currentDisplayedImageString = @"img3.png";

        }
        // AND SO ON...

    }
}
```

Comment: Does the array objects are pre-defined? Can you paste your `for` loop code also?

Comment: Hm... Are your image names really img1, img2, img3, etc? Because it seems like you wouldn't need an array in that case since the names essentially index themselves...

Comment: if your image names are like that, you can use button's tag for current index. In every action just increment once and build your imagename from button's tag. dont forget to get the modulo of tag after incrementing :)

Comment: @LyndseyScott No. The image names will be different, and possibly loaded from another view controller, but it's good to know. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *imageNames;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int currentImageIndex;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.imageNames = @[@"img1", @"img2", @"img3", @"img4"];
    self.currentImageIndex = -1;
}

- (void)changeImage {
    if (++self.currentImageIndex == self.imageNames.count) {
        self.currentImageIndex = 0;
    }
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imageNames[self.currentImageIndex]];
}

@end
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If your image names are in fact "img1," "img2," "img3," etc. you don't actually need an array to store them since the names essentially index themselves. Instead I'd recommend doing something like:

```
- (IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender {

    if (!self.userImageView.image || 
        [self.currentDisplayedImageString isEqualToString:@"img40.png"]) {
        self.currentDisplayedImageString = @"img1.png";
    }
    else {
        // Get the filename's numerical index by parsing out the numerical component
        NSString *index = [[self.currentDisplayedImageString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                            [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                           componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        // "Increment" the currentDisplayedImageString
        self.currentDisplayedImageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%@.png", index];
    }

    // Then update the image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:currentDisplayedImageString];
    self.userImageView.image = image;

}
```